# ASP.NET return Http Response from function called outside controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I just started working with asp.net mvc and am working on a legacy codebase with controllers that all have the same validation code at the front of every controller. (ie. multiple lines of the exact same code returning if the user id/key are not correct)

Is there any way to separate this out into an external function that can return an HTTP response immediately if validation fails? 
Right now I can do something like this:

```
if (!validate()) {
    return forbid("Your un or Password is incorrect");
}
```

or for a more specific message:

```
var errorMsg = validate();
if (errorMsg) {
    return forbid(errorMsg);
}
```

but if I'm going to put this at the front of most of my controllers, I'd rather have a one-liner that I takes up as little room as possible. Is there an option for bypassing the rest of the controller function and returning an HTTP response from inside my `validate()` function? Or is there possibly a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Sound like a perfect scenario for an action filter.

Comment: You can return a ForbidResult from any Method, or throw an Exception, that is handled like a HttpResponseException, but like Nkosi mentioned, an ActionFilter would fit your needs, because you don’t have to write any line of Code in any Controller.